# MySQL. Select row with same `value` which contains more "|" symbols

Tags: mysql, database

I'm sorry for incorrectly formulated question.
I will try to explain it once again.

[image]

There are two records with value 1.
I want to select ONLY ONE record that contains more "|" symbols.

If there is only one record with unique value, I should see it too.

How should I do that?

Comment: This isn't even a set data type which uses comma separation.  Normalize the data. Then, analysis on finding specific combinations becomes much simpler.  If you can't update the structure, write a view against the table which normalizes the data so you can then query the view to get the desired results.

Comment: This is completely unclear, shows no research or coding effort and appears to be just expecting an instant solution to a badly defined problem using badly defined and explained data. The tags also mention PHP but then there's nothing in it directly related to PHP. Downvoted.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe....

We simply get a length of title less the length title with the | removed to find how many | there were as a sub query.  We then join this back to your base dataset on the value and the # of occurrences.  The assumption being no value can have titles with the same number of | in them.

If such a situation exists: then both (or more) records would be returned for that value.

I say maybe because I'm assuming I understand the question.

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM table A
INNER JOIN (SELECT max(length(title)-length(replace(title,'|','')))as Occurance, value
            FROM table
            GROUP By Value) B
 on A.Value = B.value
and length(title)-length(replace(title,'|','')) = B.Occurance
```

---------------------Updated for new column

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM TABLE A
INNER JOIN (SELECT max(Components) as MaxComponents, value
            FROM Table
            GROUP By Value) B
 on A.Value = B.value
and A.Components = B.MaxComponents
```

Comment: I have managed to create another column with components number (number of components when | is exploded). How can I retrieve the record which has the highest number of components (for each value!) now?

http://imgur.com/ZNMXdEi

Comment: Updated.  All you did is eliminate the math with the new column.  So replacing `length(title)-length(replace(title,'|','')` with `components` was all that is really needed. (and I changed alias name to be more fitting on the inline view)  But my first query should still work and doesn't run the risk of being wrong if components value isn't updated each time title changes. (better have a trigger if you use the 2nd one to recalculate components value each time an update is made to title!)

Comment: Thank You for your answer, but I still can't change the code to work..
My table name is temp_active_works so what should I change in your code...?

Comment: just change the word `table` in the above to `temp_active_works`.  The 1st one I did have two )'s missing which I've corrected.

Comment: you didn't change the word table in the subquery and it doesn't need backticks (but it doesn't hurt either) I only use backticks when I have reserved/key  words to keep the SQL "clean"